# Analyze what heap consumes JUnit JavaFx

Tags: java, testing, javafx, junit, heap-memory

Is there any tool to check if I have a memory leak in my JUnit Test? Or is there a tool where I can check what the whole heap is used up?

My problem is this: I have many tests, but I just wrote new ones and now at some point I get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. So I suppose I'm doing something wrong somewhere and I don't clean something up properly because the tests themselves (individually they are relatively lightly weighted) and always work with the GUI.

Im using Intellij, Java 11 and working with JavaFx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the integrated memory profiler in IntelliJ IDEA. (Available only in ultimate version). Anyway there is this cool free tool you can use to map the entire memory flow of your application [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) *that i strongly suggest*.There is even a plugin on IntelliJ to integrate it with the common execution of your application.
Otherwise, another standard and really interesting profiler is [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html)